# Add Behavioral Profiles directly on a contact

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, experience-profile

Using Sitecore 8.2 U6

So what I want to do is iterate through 100k contacts and add pattern card(s) to the contacts. I would like to do this without requiring the users to log in or writing code to log each user in and manipulate their session.

Below is my code to add to the Behavior Profiles. It executes without issue, but when I pull the user again or visit their profile in Experience Explorer, the new pattern card has not been issued.

Any thoughts.

```
var contact = xdbContactService.GetXdbContact("user@email.com");

var profileConverterBase = BehaviorProfileConverterBase.Create();
var matchedBehaviorProfile = profileConverterBase.Convert(new ProfileData("Interests"));

// ID of a pattern card in the Interests profile
matchedBehaviorProfile.PatternId = new ID("{69E24166-3DF3-4A55-9852-95C3AA7E1242}");
matchedBehaviorProfile.NumberOfTimesScored = 2;

contact.BehaviorProfiles.Add(matchedBehaviorProfile.Id, matchedBehaviorProfile);

xdbContactService.XdbContactManager.SaveAndReleaseContact(contact);
```

My call to get a contact from xDB

```
public Contact GetXdbContact(string identifier)
{
    var contact = XdbContactRepository.LoadContactReadOnly(identifier);

    if (contact != null) return contact;

    var leaseOwner = new LeaseOwner(GetType() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), LeaseOwnerType.OutOfRequestWorker);

    contact = XdbContactRepository.CreateContact(Guid.NewGuid());

    if (contact == null) return null;

    contact.Identifiers.Identifier = identifier;

    //Setting these values allows processing and aggregation to process this contact without erroring.
    contact.System.Value = 0;
    contact.System.VisitCount = 0;

    //MAKE OTHER Contact Changes here too if you need to on Create.

    XdbContactRepository.SaveContact(contact, new ContactSaveOptions(true, leaseOwner));

    return contact;
}
```

### Update

I am not sure if this path would ever work. Looking at the `visit-scoring-profiles` query, it looks in the interactions table for head of the `best-pattern-matches` query. So just sticking a pattern on a contact won't work. It will have to come more organically from the Tracker Session.

`string fullQuery = RetrieveScoringProfiles.InjectFieldsForProfileCount(args, "{collection: "Interactions",\r\n

query:  {\r\n                                                          $and: [\r\n                                                            {"ContactId": @contactid},\r\n                                                            {"Profiles": {"$exists": 1}}\r\n                                                            ]\r\n

}\r\n                                                fields: ["_id","ContactId","StartDateTime","EndDateTime","ContactVisitIndex<<ProfileCounts>><<ProfileSelectedPatterns>>"]}");`

Comment: after you execute this code, do you see updates on the mongoDB contacts collection with this profiles added ?

Comment: @scFootsteps Nothing added to mongo. See my update in the question. Not sure if it will even work.

Comment: I had a same kind of senario recently where I needed to update a pattern card values for all the contacts depending on a user profile field value. I was not able to find a way with APIs, so took a different approach which I run the logic to adjust the persona values when users login to the website. Separated the updated and not-updated users by setting a custom facet property and custom personalization rule.

Comment: @scFootsteps my issue is that 50k users are expired users who won’t be logging in any time soon. So I have to do it without requiring the contact/user to do anything. If this was Sitecore 9, this is a solved issue. Hmmm maybe it’s time for a Sitecore ticket.

Comment: Just curious, if they are not loggin in, what's the use of updating their personas ?

Comment: To build lists in list manager. And even if they are logged out and have the analytics cookie, we can track them. Looking to know who is on the website. Also on Jan 1 everyone resets to “not registered” but the users who registered for next year. No guarantee they come back and allow me to run my code.

Comment: Aren't you missing some flush method to push data? contactManager.FlushContactToXdb(contact);

Comment: @PeterProchazka I don’t see it anywhere, but I think it has to be put on a interaction and not the contact. I can try to flush it, see what happens.

Comment: @ChrisAuer When updating the user pattern, those data will be stored in the contact collection. Can you please check if the updates are being reflected in the Contacts Collection in mongo. I already have a query to check for pattern of users in mongo. Ping me on Slack.